# Child override parent overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

The context is an event calendar using a series of `display:inline-block` divs with borders, `overflow:hidden`.

When there is a multi-day event I want to be able to blank out the border to show a continuous event 'bar'.

I have searched for solutions and the use of `::after` was the most commonly offered. I couldn't get it to work (code below).

My build is dynamic, so I tried adding an extra `position:absolute` div after the parent `pos:rel`, and that gave the same result.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<style>
.dayBox {
    display:inline-block; width:111px; border:4px solid #bcbcbc;
    margin-left:-4px; margin-bottom:-4px; background: #FFF; 
    vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; overflow:hidden; }
.event {
    position:relative; background:#99ffda; width:100%; }
.event::after {
    content:''; position:absolute; width:8px; height:100%; right:-6px; background:red; }
</style>
<div id='boxAllEvents' class='boxAllEvents'></div>
<script>
buildMonthDivs=''; 
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
buildMonthDivs += '<div id="day'+i+'" class="dayBox"><div class="event">sample text</div></div>';
}
$('#boxAllEvents').html(buildMonthDivs);
</script>
```

With this setup the red `::after` just slides under the border.

I have also seen similar questions with 'impossible' as the answer, so I hope that I am not trying to slice my lemon with a toothpick?
EDIT: [image: multi-day events]
Just to clarify the layout as regards AbdelRhman's suggestion. Each multi-day event requires a border 'patch' - but not single day events. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There is Two Solution first You remove The overFlow so the after can work  OR target the Div day of event and remove the right border

It looks like this if you go with the second choose

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<style>
        .dayBox {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 111px;
            border: 4px solid #bcbcbc;
            margin-left: -4px;
            margin-bottom: -4px;
            background: #FFF;
            vertical-align: top;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        .event {
            position: relative;
            background: #99ffda;
            width: 100%;
        }
    
        #day0 {
            border-right: none;
        }
    
        
    </style>
    <div id='boxAllEvents' class='boxAllEvents'></div>
    <script>
        buildMonthDivs = '';
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            buildMonthDivs += `<div id="day${i}" class="dayBox"><div class="event">sample text</div></div>`;
        }
        $('#boxAllEvents').html(buildMonthDivs);
    </script>
```

As I read you want it to be dynamic should happen by js as a function that adds a certain class to the parent div that has id=day0 or 1 and so on

It looks like this

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<style>
    .dayBox {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 111px;
        border: 4px solid #bcbcbc;
        margin-left: -4px;
        margin-bottom: -4px;
        background: #FFF;
        vertical-align: top;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .event {
        position: relative;
        background: #99ffda;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .remove-border {
        border-right: none;
    }
</style>
<div id='boxAllEvents' class='boxAllEvents'></div>
<script>
    buildMonthDivs = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        buildMonthDivs += `<div id="day${i}" class="dayBox"><div class="event">sample text</div></div>`;
    }
    $('#boxAllEvents').html(buildMonthDivs);

    let dayBoxs = document.querySelectorAll('.dayBox')

    dayBoxs.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        element.addEventListener('click', function addEvent() {
            element.classList.add("remove-border");
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not trying to remove the parent div border - just to put a 'patch' over it relative to the specific event. If you imagine that there are many events in each .dayBox and some of them are single-day and some multi-day. I want to only bridge (cover, patch) the border for multi-day events.

Comment: The problem here is the overflow hidden that  what makes the : :after doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I have banged my head against the overflow brick wall enough to have conceded that my lemon needs a better tool. I have a couple of lines I am working on and will post if (when) I crack it. Thx for tracking this.

Answer (score 0):

Getting out of overflow seems impossible.
Two things I did to resolve this:
1 - shift the anchor parent of the patch to a wrapper.
2 - set a descending `z-index:` for each event `.dayBox`
Here is my working test code:

```
<title>patch border</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<style>
    .dayBox { position:relative;
        display:inline-block; width:111px; border:4px solid #bcbcbc; margin-left:-4px; margin-bottom:-4px; background: #FFF; vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; z-index:1; }
    .event {
        overflow:hidden; margin:0; width:100%; padding:2px; background:#99ffda;  height:18px; z-index:2; }
    .evWrap { position:relative; width:100%; margin:6px 0; }
    .addPatch {
        position:absolute; width:4px; height:22px; top:0px; right:-4px; background:#99ffda; z-index:12; }
</style>

    <div id='boxAllEvents' class='boxAllEvents'></div>

<script>
    buildMonthDivs=''; 
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    buildMonthDivs += '<div id="day'+i+'" class="dayBox" style="z-index:'+(99-i)+'"><div class="evWrap"><div class="event">overflow this event</div><div class="addPatch"></div></div><div class="evWrap"><div class="event" style="background:#fc6fc2">another event</div><div class="addPatch"></div></div></div>';
    } 

    $('#boxAllEvents').html(buildMonthDivs);

</script>
```

that gives this result (140%)
[image: border patch]
The patch is set to the colour of the first event but would be dynamically set.
This took me quite a few hours but seems a reasonable solution. I hope that it might be of use to others.
Cheers